# Solving Constrained Optimization in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization

I'm trying to solve a constrained optimization problem in Tensorflow.

I want to add the condition to my loss function that `theta_r <= min(theta_tf)`, `theta_s >= max(theta_tf)`, `n > 1` and `Ks > 0`. Do you know how I can add such constraints to my loss function? I'm using the L-BFGS optimizer.

Below is what my loss function looks like.

```py
self.loss =  tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.theta_tf - self.theta_pred)) + \
                     tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.fbd_predict)) + \
                     tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.f_pred)) + \
                     self.weights_L2 + self.biases_L2 +\
                     1.0e-7 * (self.theta_r**2 + self.theta_s**2 + self.alpha**2 + self.n**2 + self.K_s**2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can represent the boundaries via [`tf.math.minimum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/minimum) and [`tf.math.maximum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/maximum). Then you can choose a custom loss function (e.g. MSE) that will be applied on these and add them up.

```py
min_theta_tf = tf.math.reduce_min(theta_tf)
max_theta_tf = tf.math.reduce_max(theta_tf)

loss_theta_r = tf.square(
    tf.math.maximum(theta_r, min_theta_tf)  # bound to 'min_theta_tf'
    - min_theta_tf
)
loss_theta_s = tf.square(
    tf.math.minimum(theta_s, max_theta_tf)  # bound to 'max_theta_tf'
    - max_theta_tf
)
loss_n = tf.square(tf.math.minimum(n, 1) - 1)
loss_Ks = tf.square(tf.math.minimum(Ks, 0))

loss = loss_theta_r + loss_theta_s + loss_n + loss_Ks
```